# libvirt xml: host starting with image in remote server

Tags: http, qemu, libvirt

I am trying to launch a guest vm on an ubuntu host, from a remote machine. The image for the guest is also at the remote machine(http server as image repo).
The following is the domain xml segment for disk section:

```
      <disk type='network' device='disk'>
         <driver name='qemu' type="qcow2"/>
         <source protocol="http" name="img/guest_1.qcow2">
            <host name="192.168.10.16" port="80"/>
         </source>
         <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
      </disk>
```

While i am launching the vm i get this error:

```
virsh -c qemu://hostname/system start guest_vm
error: Failed to start domain guest_vm
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2017-04-07T12:31:24.421836Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=http://192.168.10.16:80/img/guest_1.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk1: curl block device does not support writes
```

Any inputs on how to resolve the issue?

From domain xml related documents, i could see other protocols like rbd,nbd,iscsi,etc being used.Is it not possible with http ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the curl driver in QEMU (which is used for accessing disks via the http,https & ftp network protocols) only supports read-only access. You've configured a disk which requires read-write access, hence it reports an error.

Even if curl did support writes you really wouldn't want to use it. The HTTP protocol is not an efficient way to access guest disks. You should use any of  iSCSI, NBD, NFS, RBD or GlusterFS instead.